# Plane geometry and straight lines

Tags: plane-geometry

I am trying to understand a statement of a problem. Wondering how can a striaght lines in three different planes meeting at one point. Does not it imply that all the three planes are also intersecting at some line?. Can three lines in parallel planes meet at some point?.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a vertex of a cube. There are three edges meeting in this vertex, and all of them are in distinct planes. These planes do not intersect at a line, only at a point: the vertex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joao

Answer (score 0):

No three lines in parallel planes can be met at one point. To be met in one point, the three lines must intersect each other at one point, thus three intersecting planes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hussein